# How to get dynamic values from html page with LoadRunner?

Tags: loadrunner

I am using **web_reg_save_param** to get dynamic values, such as `<input type="hidden" name="lt" value="foo" />` then I can use it like :

```
web_reg_save_param("HiddenValue1", 
        "LB/IC=<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"lt\" value=\"", 
        "RB/IC=\" />", 
        "Ord=1", 
        "Search=body", 
        LAST);
```

---

However, if the `<input>` of page is like this way:
`<input type="hidden" name="lt" readonly />`
the value is set dynamically by ajax script. How can I get the value? There is no "value" property for this `<input>`.

Comment: Based on your description, there would be no value there to fetch, so please describe your issue in a better way. Exactly what value are you trying to capture, how is it display/presented etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correlation is for server returned values.   As your value is generated by local JavaScript then you should either reproduce the algorithm in the language of your script to generate the value or use the facilities of LoadRunner to execute the JavaScript function which returns the  value you seek.

Or....you can move "up the stack" for a virtual user type which will run the full client stack of the browser.   This would include types TrueClient, GUI, Citrix and RDP.

Comment: Thank you. I will try with TrueClient.